# pi 4 not connecting to router

Tags: internet

I am used to using pi via ssh, but I've moved to a new home with a new router and it's not showing up in the router's graphical interface.

Connected via ethernet directly to router, indicator lights are on at both ends of the cable.

I've tried restarting both devices and using different ports, which hasn't helped.

I don't have it set up for use with a display although I do have the physical components necessary.

Any help would be appreciated <3

Comment: "`it's not showing up in the router's graphical interface`" What does that mean? In the list of DHCP leases?? If you have a keyboard & the odd HDMI cabling (mini-full), you can get the console.

Comment: Take your SD to your PC, connect it and mount the root partition. Add/Edit the file (replace USER with your user) `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/USER` by adding a line with `* * * * * /bin/ip a >> /home/USER/ip_test`. Put SD back, boot and wait a 5 mins. Then go back to the PC and analyze which IP you see in this file. (Make sure the file has Unix-style line endings).

Comment: Do you use static ip addresses?